# Getting a type error while trying to register a username on flask

Tags: python, flask

I need you guys please to help me with this logic. I wanted my program to check whether the username or the email was already taken when the user registers. I have a proper database working fine, but when I set this code, my terminal returns this:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Here goes my register flask route:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User(name=request.form.get("name"), username=request.form.get("username"), email=request.form.get("email"), password=generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))
        existing_mail = User.query.filter_by(email=request.form.get("email")).first()
        existing_username = User.query.filter_by(username=request.form.get("username")).first()
        if existing_mail and existing_username is None:
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(user)
            session["user_id"] = user
            flash("Registered!")
            return render_template("login.html")
        elif existing_mail is not None:
            flash('Email already exists.')
            return render_template("register.html")
        elif existing_username is not None:
            flash('Username already exists.')
            return render_template("register.html")
```

This is what I think the code should do: if both mail and username return None, it means that there are no email and username matching on my database, so I can create that user. Else, If it does not returns none, it means that there's already some value/s matching on my db, so I should flash an error. I cant figure out why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: `if existing_mail is None and existing_username is None:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you don't have a default template in that function. If none of your if cases are true, the function would simply end (and return `None`). Try

```py
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User(name=request.form.get("name"), 
        # code
    return render_template("register.html")
```